# Insert a key within a line

Tags: visual-studio

When I want to edit, insert a key in between characters of any line, the cursor deletes the characters to the right, instead of just sliding it over. 
http://screencast.com/t/bOvK6wysxR

How to fix that?

Thanks for  any input..:)

Comment: Did you press 'Insert' on the keyboard ? Press it again.

Comment: 2 things shows that overwrite is on(pressed Insert key) 1. Your cursor is "fat" square not just a tiny vertical line. 2. In VS lower right corner you can see INS or OVR.

Answer (score 6):

Press Insert on your keyboard, usually near the top right. This should, allow you to insert characters rather than over write them.

Comment: Thank you! Insert key did it.